# Null pointer exception when setProgress in android progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

Why am i getting this null pointer exception. Here is my code
I am getting the exception at OnProgressUpdate method after my first execution of publishProgress from doInBackground method

```
private class ScanVideoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> callback;
        private Context context;
        private String resultOutput;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        public ScanVideoTask(AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> cb) {
            this.callback = cb;
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Get the URI of the video path & display it for a short period.
            String filename = args[0];

            int i= 0;
            while(i < 1000000)
            {
                i++;
                int progressPercentage = (int)(((float)i/(float)1000000) * (float)100);
                publishProgress(progressPercentage);
            }
            return "ok";

         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
             mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
         }

         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
             showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            }

         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println("on Post execute called" + result);
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            callback.onTaskComplete(result);
         }
     }
```

Here is what in my onCreateDialog

```
 @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Scanning video..");
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                mProgressDialog.show();
                return mProgressDialog;
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Please add a stacktrace.

Comment: Could it be you're not passing DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS to your OnCreate method? That would explain why it's not getting initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mProgressDialog` of your `ScanVideoTask` seems to be never initialized.
Where do you launch your `ScanVideoTask`?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your onPreExcecute method as described below :

```html
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
super.onPreExecute();
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
```